# How to get Quality image using CGBitmapContextCreateImage

Tags: iphone, ipad, cgbitmapcontextcreate, cgimageref

How?...
I am tring to get High Quality image using CGBitmapContextCreateImage() and tried to do it with the following code.

```
- (CGImageRef) imageForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {

    NSUInteger width = pageSize.width;
    NSUInteger height = pageSize.height;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 8;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

        void* imageData = malloc(width * height * bytesPerPixel);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, pageSize.width * 2, pageSize.height * 2, 8, pageSize.width * 8, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | CGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height));

    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height));
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical    = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, pageSize.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

    [dataSource renderPageAtIndex:pageIndex inContext:context];

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);

    return image;
}
```

But, i couldn't get the blur image, so there is some difference between the rendered image and original screen image.
I can't know the reason.
Please help me...